# How would you convert a string of long integer to BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm stuck on this portion of my code. I have a string that is stored in the input.

```
String input = ("831346848 2162638190 2014846560 1070589609 326439737");
```

The string contains long integers. I'm trying to implement them by converting each long integer into a BigInteger. For example, from the string, I need to do this:

```
 BigInteger bi1= new BigInteger("831346848");
```

and so on. The input string is extremely long, so I need to put this in some kind of loop. after I temporarily store it into bi1 I need to perform a b1.modPow(exp,mod). Then repeat the steps for each long integer in the string. That part I understand, but the part I'm confused on is how to put the input string in a loop so it will store it in bi1.

The long integers are separated by a space and each long integer in the string is different lengths.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: How big of a String are we talking here? Is it able to be stored in a String object, or are you working with a huge file?

Comment: its not a huge string, just contains about 100 long integers.

Answer (score 7):

The Java-8 way

```
List<BigInteger> bigIntegers = Stream.of(input.split(" "))
    .map(BigInteger::new)
    .map(bi -> bi.modPow(exp, bi))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You could also use `.map(BigInteger::new)` +1

Answer (score 4):

Split the string by `space` and store it in a `List` of `BigInteger`

```
String input = "831346848 2162638190 2014846560 1070589609 326439737";

List<BigInteger> bigIntegerList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

for(String value : input.split("\\s")){
     bigIntegerList.add(new BigInteger(value));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and this works great! Didn't know why I didn't think of this!

Comment: Use \\s+ instead of \\s.You can avoid the '+' sign in "\s+" if only one space is there if you like,but its not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
String nums [] = input.split (" ");
for (String num : nums) {
  BigInteger bi1= new BigInteger(num);
  // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BigInteger bi1;
for (String sbigint : input.split(" ")) {
    BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(sbigint);
    bi1 = b1.modPow(exp, mod);
}
```

The problem you described seems to missing something, the way it is `bi1` will contain the result `modPow` for the last long integer in your string.

Answer (score 0):

You need a regular expression like "\s+", which means: split whenever at least one whitespace is encountered. The full Java code is:

```
try {
   List<BigInteger> bigList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
   for(String subStr : input.split("\\s+")){
      bigList.add(new BigInteger(subStr));
   }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // 
}
```

You can avoid the '+' sign in "\s+" if only one space is there if you like,but its not necessary.

Comment: I wouldn't catch `Exception` unless there was a clear purpose in doing so.

Comment: Because the constructor could throw a `NumberFormatException` ?
Actually I'd use the try-catch just inside the loop so that the exception would only skip the offending string and still continue the rest of the loop.